# My dovecot can’t receive email in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, dovecot, ubuntu-18.04

My Linux version is Ubuntu 18.04, postfix work well.
After some dovecot configuration, when I type

```
netstat -ntl
```

I found that port “993” and “995” in the displayed list. And I type

```
telnet localhost 993
```

It prints

```
Trying ::1...
Connected to ***.com
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I am feel weird that there isn’t “dovecot is already ”.
And I email to this account, it also can’t receive.

And there are some configuration.
/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
!include_try /usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d/*.protocol

protocols = imap pop3
listen = *, ::

ssl = no
# ssl_cert =< /etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
# ssl_key =< /etc/ssl/private/dovecot.key

dict {

}
!include conf.d/*.conf

!include_try local.conf
```

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf

```
ssl = required

ssl_cert = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/dovecot/private/dovecot.key

disable_plaintext_auth = no
```

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf

```
disable_plaintext_auth = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain
!include auth-system.conf.ext
```

Comment: Do you intend to enable SSL or disable SSL? Your configuration specifies both.

Comment: @MichaelHampton But if I changed them to same, netstat list’s port changed to “993” and “143” ,and it will stop service after telnet.